# Computing $\int_V(x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz,$ where $V$ is the intersection of two spheres in $\Bbb R^3.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$\int_V(x^2+y^2+z^2)dxdydz,$$ where $V$ is the intersection of the spheres $x^2+^2+z^2\le1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2z.$

**My attempt:**

$$\begin{aligned}\begin{cases}x^2+y^2+z^2&\le 1\\x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2&\le 1\end{cases}\\ \\\text{for the orthogonal projection of the intersection}\\\\1-z^2&=1-(z-1)^2\\2z-1&=0\\z&=\frac12\\\implies \boxed{x^2+y^2\le\frac14}\\\psi(r,\varphi,z)&=(r\cos\varphi,r\sin\varphi,z),\\J_\psi(r,\varphi,z)&=r\\S=\{(r,\varphi,z):0\le r\le\frac12,0\le\varphi\le2\pi,1-\sqrt{1-r^2}\le z\le\sqrt{1-r^2}\}\\\int_Vf(x,y,z)dxdydz&=\int_{\psi(S)}f(x,y,z)\\&=\int_0^{1/2}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{1-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}(r^2+z^2)rdzd\varphi dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^{1/2}r\left(r^2z+\frac{z^3}3\right)\Big|_{1-\sqrt{1-r^2}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\\&=2\pi\int_0^{1/2}r\left(2r^2\sqrt{1-r^2}-r^2+\frac23(1-r^2)^{3/2}-\frac43+\sqrt{1-r^2}+r^2\right)dr\\&=2\pi\int_0^{1/2}\left(2r^3\sqrt{1-r^2}+\frac23r(1-r^2)^{2/3}-\frac43r+r\sqrt{1-r^2}\right)dr\end{aligned}$$

Side computations:

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\sqrt{1-r^2}^3-(1-\sqrt{1-r^2})^3}3&=\frac{(1-r^2)^{3/2}-1+3\sqrt{1-r^2}-3(1-r^2)+(1-r^2)^{3/2}}3\\&=\frac23(1-r^2)^{3/2}-\frac43+\sqrt{1-r^2}+r^2\\\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^{1/2} 2r^3\sqrt{1-r^2}&=\begin{bmatrix}du=-\frac13r\sqrt{1-r^2}dr\implies  u=(1-r^2)^{3/2}\\v=-6r^2\implies dv=-12rdr \end{bmatrix}\\&=-6r^2(1-r^2)^{3/2}\Big|_0^{1/2}-\int_0^{1/2} -12r(1-r^2)^{3/2}dr\\&=-6r^2(1-r^2)^{1/2}\Big|_0^{1/2}-\frac{12}5(1-r^2)^{5/2}\Big|_0^{1/2}\\\int_0^{1/2}\frac23r(1-r^2)^{1/2}&=-\frac13\int_0^{1/2}-2r(1-r^2)^{1/2}dr\\&=-\frac29(1-r^2)^{3/2}\Big|_0^{1/2}\\\int_0^{1/2}r(1-r^2)^{1/2}dr&=-\frac12\int_0^{1/2}-2r(1-r^2)^{1/2}dr\\&=-\frac13(1-r^2)^{3/2}\Big|_0^{1/2}\end{aligned}$$

I stopped here because this already got too long and it wouldn't work on exam. Is there any better method?

Comment: My first instinct would be to try spherical coordinates, since the integrand simplifies the most in that case.

Comment: @Jose27, halfway through doing this, I thought of that, but my brain couldn't work on the bounds in that case after being up since 5 a.m.

Comment: A starting point would be that if $\theta$ is the angle with the positive $z$-axis, and $\rho$ is the length of your vectors, then your two equations for the spheres become $\rho\leq 1$ and $\rho\leq 2\cos\theta$, so you'll have to look at the regions where $2\cos\theta<1$ and $2\cos\theta\geq 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spherical coordinates,

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

$S_1: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ is $\rho \leq 1$

$S_2: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2z$ is $\rho \leq 2 \cos \phi, 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$

At their intersection, $\rho = 2 \cos\phi = 1 \implies \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$

For $~0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/3$, $\rho$ is bound above by the sphere $S_1$ and for $\pi/3 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2$, $\rho$ is bound above by the sphere $S_2$.

So the integral can be written as,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/3} \int_0^1 \rho^4 \sin \phi ~ d\rho ~ d\phi ~ d\theta ~ + ~$

$~~~~~ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\cos\phi} \rho^4 \sin \phi ~ d\rho ~ d\phi ~ d\theta$

Both integrals are straightforward to compute. In the second one, after integrating wrt $\rho$, you can substitute $\cos \phi = t$ and then $\sin \phi ~ d\phi = - dt$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have to practise in spherical coordinates more, but this is a great illustration for start.

Comment: @Dolphin you are welcome. Please feel free to come back if you have any questions on it, now or later.

Answer (score 1):

The integral can also be done with only one integral in spherical coordinates. The trick is to integrate w.r.t. the angular variables first. We need $\phi$ as a function of $\rho$, giving the bounds as

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\rho}{2}\right)}\rho^4\sin\phi\:d\phi\:d\rho\:d\theta = 2\pi \int_0^1 \rho^4-\frac{\rho^5}{2}\:d\rho = \frac{7\pi}{30}$$

This method has the added benefit of reducing to an integral of polynomials instead of trig.